# On Android, is library able to receive notification that app is backgrounded / foregrounded?

Tags: android

I'm writing a library that uses a Timer to perform scheduled background processing. One key feature is to conserve battery life, so I'd like to have my library pause the background processing when the app isn't actively used.

Ideally, it would be great if equivalents to Activity.onPause() and Activity.onResume() could be received by my library without having to create an API for it. I don't want to have to rely on the dev, who's implementing my library, to have to call MyLibrary.onPause() and MyLibrary.onResume() throughout the various activities of their app.

Are there any other solutions apart from API's ? I thought maybe there is a broadcast that my library could register for - but I haven't found anything useful at the moment... looking for suggestions...

Thanks !!

Comment: I'm in two minds about voting to close this question as it is quite broad and also seems slightly confused. Unless your understanding of a "library" is somewhat different to mine, a "library" is not an 'active' entity. A library is a collection of various components (classes etc) which can be instantiated and run by whatever code is using it, As such, an entire "library" could not possibly 'listen' for some event to indicate that the application which is using it has changed from one running state to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks%28android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks%29) to set up a listener for Activity life cycle events. It's API 14+ but this should not be a big deal nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some few Hacks

- [**`View.isShown()`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isShown%28%29)

by taking in an Activity as a context, in your library, and continuously checking for `isShown()` on its `DecorView`

```
MyLibrary(Context context){
 if(context instanceof Activity){
        boolean activityStatus =    ((Activity)c).getWindow().getDecorView().isShown();
//true means it is shown, and you start your loop and keep checking something like this
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(;;){
                    boolean tempStatus = ((Activity)c).getWindow().getDecorView().isShown() 
                    && activityStatus && /*((Activity)c).getWindow().
                    getDecorView().isLaidOut() if api 19+*/;

                    if(tempStatus){
                        //it is still showing or its previous value is being maintained
                    }else{
                        //it has been changed..
                    }}}});}//ending braces
```

some limitations will be that, when a `DialogFragment` is shown it might check out true, maybe or maybe not, but you can check if the current focus on a View is on that Window by doing `getWindow().getCurrentFocus()` which will return a non-null; you can try this and see

- [**`Activity.hasWindowFocus()`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#hasWindowFocus%28%29)

which will always return `false` on `onPause()` and true when your `Activity` is on

Answer (score 0):

There are many misconceptions in your questions so it's hard to answer but I can give you a few advices.

First you should never use a Timer to schedule work on Android. You should use Handler to schedule UI events and AlarmManager with a Service (like IntentService) for background work which is independent from Activities.

If the work is directly tied to your Activities, you should not schedule the work using AlarmManager but use a bound Service. This kind of service automatically stops when no Activity is connected to it.

If the work is independent from your Activities, then the best way to save battery is to choose an appropriate running frequency in AlarmManager and use inexact repeating. This way the system will likely run all pending tasks in a single batch to save power.

I invite you to read the documentation of all the components I mentioned.